Maximizing Self-Intersections in a 120-degree Turning Path
A person walks on the Euclidean plane, adhering to the following rules:

They always walk in a straight line.
When they turn, it's always 120 degrees to the left.
They eventually return to their starting point.
Each straight line segment they walk along is different (i.e., no retracing steps).
The total number of turns made is 3n, where n is an integer greater than or equal to 2.

What is the maximum possible number of self-intersecting points their walking route can have?
Additional Notes:

A self-intersecting point is where two distinct line segments of the path cross each other.
The path can be self-intersecting but cannot overlap itself (i.e., no walking along the same line segment multiple times).

I'm interested in finding an upper bound for the number of self-intersections and understanding the structure of paths that achieve this maximum. Any insights or approaches would be appreciated!
Update
I believe I may have found the intuitive construction for the problem, but I do not know if this is the correct answer.
So here is the construction I thought of: Take $3n$ lines that are parallel to $1$, $\omega$, $\omega^2$ directions respectively. Among these lines, the horizontal lines are numbered from top to bottom, the lines along the $\omega$ direction are numbered from bottom left to top right, and the lines along the $\omega^2$ direction are numbered from bottom right to top left, all from $1$ to $n$. We refer to these lines by their number and direction as subscripts: $l_1, l_2, ..., l_n, l_{\omega}, l_{2\omega}, ..., l_{n\omega}, l_{\omega^2}, l_{2\omega^2}, ..., l_{n\omega^2}$, and call them category 1, 2, and 3 respectively. We make sure the triangle formed by $l_1, l_{\omega},$ and $l_{\omega^2}$ lie above $l_1$, to the bottom left of $l_{\omega}$, and to the bottom right of $l_{\omega^2}$. For the category 3 lines $l_{i\omega^2}$, take the intersection point with the $(n+1-i)$-th lines of the other two directions as the vertex (i.e., the turning point), where $i = 1, 2, ..., n$.
Define a permutation $\pi$ of 1 to $n$:

When $2 | n-1$, $\pi(i) = $

$n$, if $i = 1$
$n-i$, if $2 | i$
$n+2-i$, if $2 | i-1$


When $2 | n$, $\pi(i) = $

$n+1-i$, if $i = 1$ or $2 | i$ and $i \in \{\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{2} + 1\}$
$n-i$, if $2 | i$ and $i \neq \frac{n}{2} + 1$
$n+2-i$, if $2 | i-1$



we can tell that $\pi$ is a cyclic permutation.
Let the person move sequentially on $l_{\omega}, l_{n\omega^2}, l_{1}, l_{\pi(1)\omega}, l_{(n+1-\pi(1))\omega}, l_{\pi(1)}, ..., l_{\pi^{-1}(1)\omega}, l_{(n+1-\pi^{-1}(1))\omega}, l_{\pi^{-1}(1)}$, turning whenever it encounters the next line.
For the intersection of the non-parallel $i$-th line and $j$-th line, it seems that when $i+j \leq n$, this point must be a self-intersection point or a vertex. Exactly $\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]$ of the above intersections are vertices. Therefore, the path at this time has at least $\frac{3}{2}n(n-1) - \left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]$ self-intersection points.
I'm not aware of how this can be proven right now, it would be great if anyone can come up with some way if it is actually correct.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please include whatever partial results you've found, any conjectures you made, and evidence you have to support or refute them. This will help people avoid duplicating your effort or telling you things you already know. ... Good luck!

BTW, this seems like a nice question. Just sketching quickly, I came up with a 12-crossing path...have you managed to do better than that?

OK. I think I've managed to do better than that...but following Blue's remark, I'm going to wait until you tell us what you've done so far.

Oh...by the way, I was working with $n = 1$, so $3$ turns. Also: to amplify your question, you can click the grey "Edit" just below the question, and somewhat to the left of your name. It took me quite a while to notice that when I was starting out.

My apologies for my earlier comment --- I was working with both 60 and 120 degree turns. And when you said the total number of turns, I mis-read that as the total "turning number" as defined in the Whitney-Graustein paper on turning numbers of plane curves.
Anyhow, for 9 edges, which is (I guess) your $n = 3$ case, I came up with this 8-intersection drawing:

That seems to match your estimate of an upper bound for this case. And this drawing:

generalizes nicely to give a minimum of crossings (namely $n - 1$) for any $n$. (This is definitely a min, because of the Whitney-Graustein theorem).
This isn't really an answer, but it does provide a lower-bound on the count of crossings, and a confirmation that your current upper bound seems to be easily achievable, at least in the $n = 3$ case.
